# Dynamic vs Options binding in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I re-read documentation several times, and I am not getting it. What is the difference between these two? Is it only that with dynamic you don't have to define "bindable" attributes? If so, why would one not just use dynamic always. What are the use cases for one over the other? I am just confused about this and would like somebody if possible to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Options Binding are only available for custom-attributes, not custom-elements. They are useful when you do not know the name of all the possible properties or when there are too many properties and you are a lazy person like me.

So, instead of declaring several bindable properties

```
export class MyCustomAttribute {
    @bindable prop1;

    prop1Changed(newValue, oldValue) { }

    @bindable prop2;

    prop2Changed(newValue, oldValue) { }

    @bindable prop3;

    prop3Changed(newValue, oldValue) { }
}
```

you can decorate de class with `@dynamicOptions` and use a generic method to detect which property has been set

```
export class MyCustomAttribute {

  propertyChanged(name, newValue, oldValue){
    switch(name){
      case 'prop1':
        //do something
        break;
      case 'prop2':
        //do something
        break;
      case 'prop3':
        //do something
        break;
      default:
        //do something
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Why not use `@dynamicOptions` all the time? Because you would be doing unnecessary conditions most of the time, which is not cool :)

Hope this helps!